# Struggling with The C Programming Language exercise 1-13

Tags: c

The exercise that I am struggling with says "Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in it's input."
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int length[15];
    int i, j, k;
    i = j = k = 0;
    int count, c, state = OUT;
    for(i; i<15; i++)
        length[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if ((c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t') && (state == IN))
        {
            state = OUT;
            if ((count > 0) && (count < 16))
                length[count -1]++;
            if (count >= 16)
                length[14]++;
        }
        if ((c != '\n' && c != ' ' && c != '\t') && (state == OUT))
        {
            state = IN;
            count = 0;
        }
        if (state == IN)
            count++;
    }
    for(j; j<15; j++)
    {
        printf("length %d\t",j+1);
        for(k; k<length[j]; k++)
            printf("X");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code with a test like:

```
a bb ccc  
^d
```

or:

```
aaa bb c  
^d
```

it gives me a histogram with just one 'X' in the 1 column. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How far did ***you*** succeed in ***debugging*** your problem? Is there an error in filling or in printing the table? Single-step through your program - at what point does something unexpected happen?  (Hint: lookup the syntax of the for-statement, in particular the initialisation expression.)

Comment: Well, there's only one word of length one in each input, so isn't it supposed to only print one X in the 1 column?

Comment: You are writing `for` loops incorrectly. Ackquire a habit of writing `(for i = 0;...`.  The other problem is that your state machine will miss the last word if the file foes not end with a whute space.

Comment: @n.m. Good observation about whute space, too. (I love that word, by the way; if I could give you an additional upvote just for that, I would :P )

Comment: @Amadan all credit to my phone keyboard

Answer (score 4):

The "normal" way to write a `for` loop is:

```
for (k = 0; k < length[j]; k++)
```

You skip the initialisation step, relying on the `i = j = k = 0` set up at the start of the program. Setting aside the fact that most compilers will complain (issue warnings) about an unused value `k` here, a deeper problem is the fact that this loop is *nested* inside another loop. The first iteration goes through okay, `k` starts at `0` and goes up to `length[0] - 1` as it should; but on the second iteration, `k` starts at `length[0]` and goes up to `length[1] - 1`, which is likely to be a lower number, therefore shortening or skipping the bar for this line. And if it did get printed, the "bar" (if you'll excuse the pun) will have been set higher, so each successive line will be shortened by the maximum length of the preceding lines.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I didn't see that myself!

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code has been already pointed out by @Amadan.

I'm going to present you your code with a few `printf` statements to help isolate the problem.

If you are not able to or not comfortable with a debugger, I think you need to get acquainted with one.

A poor man's way of debugging is by inserting `printf` statements at crucial places to understand how the code is working.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int length[15];
    int i, j, k;
    i = j = k = 0;
    int count, c, state = OUT;
    for(i; i<15; i++)
        length[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
       printf("%c\n", c);
       printf("Came here 1.\n");
        if ((c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t') && (state == IN))
        {
           printf("Came here 2. Count= %d\n", count);
            state = OUT;
            if ((count > 0) && (count < 16))
                length[count -1]++;
            if (count >= 16)
                length[14]++;
            printf("length[%d] = %d\n", count-1, length[count-1]);
        }
        else if ((c != '\n' && c != ' ' && c != '\t') && (state == OUT))
        {
           printf("Came here 3.\n");
            state = IN;
            count = 1;
        }
        else if (state == IN)
        {
           printf("Came here 4.\n");
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("Didn't expect here.\n");
        }
    }
    for(j; j<15; j++)
    {
        printf("length %d\t",length[j]);
        for(k; k<length[j]; k++)
            printf("X");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```